# Micronaut Data JDBC and Postgres Arrays

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

Do you know if Micronaut Data JDBC supports Postgres array using Java array/collections or do I need to define a custom type? If so how? I looked at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#jdbcDataTypes but did not see any information on array types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like array types does not work out of the box unless you specify the column data type as `DataType.OBJECT` e.g.

```
@MappedEntity
public class Article{
  //...
  @MappedProperty(type = DataType.OBJECT)
  private String[] labels;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem to map Array of Enum type to Postgresql Array type column.
I did use custom attribute converter for 1) convert enum-array to string-array and 2) PgArray object to enum-array.

```
    @Singleton
    class CustomEnumTypesConverter : AttributeConverter<Array<CustomEnum>, Any> {

   override fun convertToPersistedValue(
        entityValue: Array<CustomEnum>,
        context: ConversionContext
    ) = entityValue.map { it.name }.toTypedArray()

    override fun convertToEntityValue(
        persistedValue: Any,
        context: ConversionContext
    ) = ((persistedValue as PgArray).array as Array<String>)
        .map { CustomEnum.valueOf(it) }.toTypedArray()
}

enum class CustomEnum {
    VALUE_1, VALUE_2, VALUE_3
}



@Entity
data class MyEntity(

....

    @field:TypeDef(type = DataType.OBJECT, converter = CustomEnumTypesConverter::class)
    val customEnumTypes: Array<CustomEnum>,
...


)
```

The interface to implement in converter is

```
import io.micronaut.data.model.runtime.convert.AttributeConverter
```

I've micronautVersion=3.5.3